# Visual Studio Code jump from console to code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code (Version 1.53.2). I would like to know if it is possible to have a feature like *when an Error is raised* clicking in the console in line XXX, goes directly to line XXX
in my script.

For example:

File "example.py", **line 438**, in 
Amplitudes, Decays, Fitted_curves = LM_fit()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I would like to click on line 438 and that automatically goes to that line in my code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Click` ing on the line.

Comment: I did. But doesn’t work.